# Is there a way to remove like count in Facebook Like Box widget?

Tags: php, facebook, widget, facebook-like

I know that tampering with their widget isn't allowed but how do sites like these hide their like counts and it doesn't seem like the widget has been edited. Is there a proper way to do this?

http://www.marketing-interactive.com/

http://www.humanresourcesonline.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%23%21%2Fpages%2FMarketing-Magazine%2F174907875860500&amp;width=314&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=427" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:314px; height:427px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

They're adding a `height=427` parameter to the IFRAME URL, which results in the "faces" area at the bottom, and its accompanying fan count, being hidden from view. They're keeping `show_faces=true` because otherwise the Like count will be written next to the Like button.

There's a slightly weird double-line at the bottom as a result of this approach, but while earlier I wrote it was undocumented, [the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) actually references the height param (it's just not in the plugin generator form), so it appears this is supported.

Comment: Thanks, I think this one explains it.

Comment: I already said all this. I even provided links to the documentation and live demos that allow you to replicate the situation first-hand.

Answer (score 0):

It's because they're using a [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/), not a [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

These are two different things, and the individual like buttons in a Like Box don't have the counts when "show faces" is enabled (though the counts *are* instead displayed elsewhere in the box).

Comment: I could be mistaken but I think the OP is referring to the share button, not the like box. See the top left content corner on [this page](http://www.marketing-interactive.com/news/28295).

Comment: @ShaneC: That's not the page he linked to, and he said "like box" in both the title and the tags.

Comment: I understand, however as you pointed out the Like amount isn't defaulted in the Like Box. Either way between our two answers he has the solution, so this should solve his problem.

Comment: (You'll also notice that the CSS directives you refer to are found in one of the stylesheets that's served directly from Facebook. When you click on the Share button -- which is deprecated anyway -- the count does appear, so I believe that this is the intended behaviour.)

Comment: I'm aware of that, however they can easily be augmented by adding characteristics to those classes on a local site.

Comment: I am referring to the Like Box. However, no matter what option I disable, it still shows the like count beside the [Like] button (that is inside the Like Box). I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

For instance, when I put https://www.facebook.com/marketingmagazine.group inside the Facebook Page URL field, the preview on the right shows the no. of likes.

Comment: @catandmouse: You just go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/, and there is no count there. Make sure "show faces" is on.

Comment: There is still a like count but it's at the bottom (just above "show faces"). The sites I posted don't have the like count and don't have the "show faces" so I was wondering how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

To make Like Boxes I still just goto Facebook's "generator" here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/.

When your putting in settings you **uncheck "Show Faces"**.

This changes the resulting code they give you to: `show_faces=false`.

Answer (score -1):

*Note: This answer is assuming you mean the Share Button, and not Like Box*

They used a Facebook provided CSS to make the elements have a CSS property of `display: none;`.

On the `span` elements with the classes:

```
fb_share_count_nub_right
fb_share_count
```

Add the class `fb_share_no_count` on both of them.

Comment: Those classes aren't used in the like box; [the API simply displays the buttons like this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/).

Comment: I'm making the assumption that the OP meant Share or Like button, as the Like Box doesn't need to display a count.

Comment: There is no variant of [the Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) that has a label "share". The Share button is something else, [which has been deprecated for several months now](http://mashable.com/2011/02/27/facebook-like-button-takes-over-share-button-functionality/).

Comment: I'm not really understanding why you're sitting here arguing semantics. I have provided a solution for the OP if he chooses to implement the Share button. You have provided one if he intends to proceed with the Like Box. Is there any reason not to be content with that outcome?

Comment: I'm not arguing semantics. I'm trying to point out that you're talking about something completely unrelated to this question, but you're not listening. :(

Comment: No, I fully understand what the OP's post indicates in the way of the Like Box. Having spent quite a while developing Facebook apps, I know that sometimes people get confused with the terminology. As you pointed out, there is no solution (because it's already fixed) for the case of the Like Box. I, as an alternative, gave an explanation in the event the OP was confused on the question. I see no harm in providing options for answers.

Comment: Your answer is even wrong when relating to those other Facebook widgets, as explained above.